# Email Database - Query only shows 'opened' emails; I want all sent e-mails and when they were opened

Tags: sql, exacttarget

I have query below that only pulls e-mails sent that haven't been opened. I want it to pull all e-mails sent (within the where timeframe) and show the [OpenDate] whether it is null or not.

I'm using Exact Target (Marketing Cloud)'s SQL Query. Any ideas why the below doesn't work?

```
SELECT j.EmailName, s.EmailAddress, j.JobID, j.DeliveredTime, s.SubscriberKey, max(o.EventDate) as OpenDate FROM  _Job j
INNER JOIN _Sent se ON j.JobID = se.JobID
INNER JOIN _Subscribers s ON se.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
LEFT OUTER JOIN _Open o ON se.JobID = o.JobID
WHERE se.EventDate >= GetDate()-14 AND se.EventDate <= GetDate() -7
GROUP BY j.JobID, j.EmailName, j.DeliveredTime, s.EmailAddress, s.SubscriberKey
```

Comment: what is the output you are getting? Are you not receiving any output?

Comment: Ah disregard previous comment if you read. The above returns nothing - 0 records. If I change LEFT OUTER JOIN to LEFT JOIN then I get all of the Sent emails with a value in o.EventDate (which means they opened the e-mail). I do not receive any records where o.EventDate=null

Comment: try joining _Open to _Job instead of to _Sent.